# SharedPreferences - not working

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am using sharedpreference to store the user name. When i did this inside my activity it is working fine. But when i pass to a common class ( which save the values )   then it fails. Could you please guide me to the place where my code need correction ?
Thanks in advance

```
public class Login extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{
String userId,password,userType,key="userId";  ;
EditText etName,etPassword,etUserType;
Button go; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    initialize();
}
private void initialize(){

    etUserType=(EditText) findViewById (R.id.etUserType);   
    etName=(EditText) findViewById (R.id.etName);
    etPassword=(EditText) findViewById (R.id.etPassword);    
    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGo);
    go.setOnClickListener(this); 
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    userType=etUserType.getText().toString(); 
    userId=etName.getText().toString();
    password=etPassword.getText().toString();   

    if (userId.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() ) { 
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("   Alert  ");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("User Name and Password are mandatory");
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    }else{


          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
          try {
            List<UserType> userType = PosClient.getUserTypes();
            User user = PosClient.getUser(userId, userType.get(0)); 
            LastUser lastUser = new LastUser();
            lastUser.saveUser(key, Integer.toString(user.getUserId()));  ()); 

            if  (password.equals(user.getPassword())){ 
                Intent sendBack = new Intent();
                Bundle backpack = new Bundle();
                backpack.putString("command", "proceed");  
                backpack.putSerializable("user", user);
                sendBack.putExtras(backpack);  
                setResult(RESULT_OK, sendBack);
                finish();
            }else{
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("   Alert  ");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("User Name / Password is invalid");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
          } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) { 
              e1.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e1) { 
              e1.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
}



public class LastUser extends Activity{
SharedPreferences file;
public static String filename = "MySharedFile";

public  String checkUser(){  
    file = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
    String userName = file.getString("waitername", "NOID"); 
    return userName;
} 

public void saveUser(String key,String value) {  
    filename = "MySharedFile";
    file = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = file.edit();
    editor.putString(key,value);
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

Error details :

```
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:153)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at com.example.restaurent.LastUser.saveUser(LastUser.java:21)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at com.example.restaurent.Login.onClick(Login.java:77)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-27 12:27:41.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2983):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is at line number 21 in LastUser class?

Comment: file = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);

Comment: try this **mActivity.getSharedPreferences(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
public class LastUser extends Activity{         //<<<<<<<<
SharedPreferences file;
public static String filename = "MySharedFile";
  // your code here
}
```

you are trying to Create an instance of Activity Class for Accessing methods from other Activty which is not right way. change your code as:

```
public class LastUser {
SharedPreferences file;
public static String filename = "MySharedFile";


public  String checkUser(Context context){  
    file = context.getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
    String userName = file.getString("waitername", "NOID"); 
    return userName;
} 

public void saveUser(String key,String value,Context context) {  
    filename = "MySharedFile";
    file = context.getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = file.edit();
    editor.putString(key,value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Now for Creating SharedPreferences from Activity just pass Activity Context to methods as :

```
 LastUser lastUser = new LastUser();
 lastUser.saveUser(key, Integer.toString(user.getUserId()),Login.this);
```

Comment: What is the use of LastUser class ? Don't you think it is redundant ?

Comment: @Amit : user1822729 want to separate SharedPreferences code from Login Activity

Comment: But you are reputed person (19.2K is awesome) and instead of correcting him you are just helping him spoil his program design design... there can be two function getLastUserData() and saveUserData() which can replace this class... Can't they ?

Comment: In the line file = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);getSharedPreferences is not visible in LastUser Class

Comment: @user1822729 : see my answer just do same

Comment: Amit, This same saveUser logic is called in many other class. I am trying to keep this common code in another class so that the code looks clean and make other to understand it with less effort

Comment: @Amit : Thanks , but separation of code is best practice instead of making common methods in same class . like in this post user1822729 is separating Creation / retrieving logic of SharedPreferences in separate class which is very useful in case of if in future he wants to use these methods in other activities or components

Comment: @Amit : and he is doing in right way but not passing context of Activity or Components to non Activity class for Creating SharedPreferences

Comment: Thanks Prosper ... it is working after passing the context...

Thanks Amit I will check your suggestions too...

Comment: I am not saying whether he was doing it right way or not... As an android programmer I am just saying whatever he was doing was not right... @user1822729 You don't need a separate class just to save the Last user's login information.. If you have a user class than you can have an object i.e. last user and save it but having a class just to call its too non static methods is a wrong approach.

Comment: @Amit : as an Android Programmer first point is just avoid use of static field or behavior in Application as much as possible because statics are first reason for if memory leak caused by application.and finally your answer is also welcome if you have some better suggestion then share it plz

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `getSharedPreference()` from an activity which is not yet started.. I suggest you to place the `checkUser()` and `saveUser()` code too in Login Activity and remove the LastUser Activity completely.

You also understood the Activity concept wrong. An Activity is not like any other Java class it should only deal with the UI, for backing objects use POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

please place below one in your code

```
 SharedPreferences file=null;
 file= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
file = this.getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
```

Instead of,

```
file = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for store value into shared preferences and get value from shared preferences, it will solve your problem.

For Store Value into shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("Value", "Dipak Keshariya");
prefsEditor.commit();
```

For Get Value from Shared Preferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String mValue = myPrefs.getString("Value");
```

Comment: In this case , Do we need to pass the context ?

Comment: ya, you can also pass the context instead of this in above code.